# Defining a function $f$ on a compact connected surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I was proving this result that for $M$, connected surface with $K>0$ and $H$ constant, $M$ is a sphere of radius $1/\sqrt K$.

$H$ is for mean curvature and $K$ for Gaussian.

I was able to prove that, however, i saw a problem which states that if $f(x)$ is a function which takes max. (or min) value at $p$ ($p$ is the point where $H^2-K$ takes the maximum value). What can we say about $f(x)+c$ where $c$ is a constant, can $c$ be $2H$ or $-2H$?

I have no idea how to deal this second problem. Since $H$ is constant, and $H^2-K=(k_1-k_2)^2/4$, I don't know how to use all this. Please help me. I am stuck.
[image: Here is the problem]

Comment: It is  unclear what you want to ask. There's nothing you can say about $f$? Is there any extra conditions on $f$?

Comment: No, the problem only says that $f$ takes max. or min. at $p$, Can $c$ be $2H$ or $-2H$?

Comment: What is your definition of $c$?

Comment: $c$ is a constant. The problem asks to show if this constant can be $2H,-2H$ or not.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If $c$ is an arbitrary constant, why can't you set it to be $2H$ or $-2H$??

Comment: There is a condition on $f$ that it takes max. or min. value at $p$. May be this has something to do with $c$. If I was sure, why would I ask it here. I am stuck here

Comment: But there's no way we can answer your question, unless you can tell us more about your $c$. Why is there such a $c$? And what is $f$? Which book/note are you using?

Comment: Differential geometry and its applications by John Oprea

Comment: Which chapters?

Comment: Chapter 3,  exercise 3.5.10

Comment: Not sure it I get the same edition as you. In my 3.5.10, I cannot find any $f$ and $c$.

Comment: Considering you see the hints given in that edition, and $f$ defined as above, can you give me an idea how to get information about $c$. I can see that the radius of sphere is $1/H$

Comment: So I think $f = H^2  - K$?

Comment: Why is that? This would imply $f(x)$ is identically zero

Comment: Ah you mean $f(x)=-K(x)+H^2$, ahan , then $f$ has max, value at $p$

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look of the original question, I think I can come up with some hints.

So you need to consider the function $f(x) = H^2 - K(x) = \frac{(k_1 - k_2)^2}{4}$ defined on the surface $S$. Note $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in S$. There are two cases.

- $f(x)$ is identically zero. Then $k_1 = k_2$. Together with $\frac{k_1 + k_2}{2} = c$, we have $k_1 = k_2 = c$. Thus $K = c^2$ is constant. Then use Theorem 3.5.5 in the book.
- If $f(x)$ is not identically zero. Let $p \in S$ so that $f$ attains its maximum ($S$ is compact, so one can find such a $p$). Now as $S$ has constant mean curvature $c = \frac{k_1 + k_2}{2}$, then

$$k_1 - k_2 = k_1 + k_2 - 2k_2 = 2c - 2k_2$$

Thus $f$ is maximized if and only if $k_2$ is minimized. Similarly,

$$k_1 - k_2 = 2k_1 - k_1 - k_2 = 2k_1 - 2c$$

Thus $f$ is maximized if and only if $k_1$ is maximized. So $k_1$ is maximized at $p$ and $k_2$ is minimized at $p$. Then try to use Hilbert's lemma.

Comment: First thing, about f being identically zero means we can choose any $c$ we want? or we can say nothing about $c$?
Secondly, I see why $2H$ appears in $f(x)+c$, but Why do we need to use Hilbert's lemma after this?

Comment: What does Hilbert lemma tell you?

Comment: It tells me that Gaussian curvature is $<=0$ at $p$, how would that help?

Comment: and Thank you for your help, most of the things are clear now.

Comment: $K\le 0$ is not possible from your assumption (and you are wellcome). @Ali

Comment: sorry again, what happens if $f$ is identically zero? adding any $c$ wouldn't  cause a problem?

Comment: It seems that your argument in step 2 only shows that when $f$ is maximized, $k_2$ achieves either a minimum or a maximum. (Because of the power of $2$ in $f$.) Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ali: According to the hint in the book, when $f$ is identically zero you need to use the 3.5.5

Comment: That power of two is actually not important. As by definition $k_1 \leq k_2$, so $f$ is maximized if and only if $k_1 - k_2$ is maximized. @mollyerin

Comment: Honestly, I feel lost in the first part. I understood the second one completely.

Comment: because if i use 3.5.5, i will get that curvature at each point is zero and then?

Comment: Please see the edit @Ali

Comment: What did you do to that? It looks worse now :(

Comment: Please explain the changes, it is very confusing now

Comment: I am not sure if my Theorem 3.5.5 is the same as yours. In my books Theorem 3.5.5 is the Liberman theorem, which says that if $S$ has constant $K$, then $S$ is a sphere.

Comment: @John it is the same theorem in my book but what do i get by applying it?

Comment: Now $K $ is constant.....

Comment: This doesn't contradict anything.

Comment: Please don't mind, I might be annoying but I need to understand what is the conclusion. Second part is 100% ok, but what's wrong with the first one?

Comment: I think either $f$ is identically $2H$ or $-2H$, or we can't take $c$ as desired

Comment: Now $K$ is constant, so the theorem 3.5.5 imply that $S$ is a shpere. Isn't that what you want to show?